# How to open class with alias_method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I've been reading through Metaprogrammin Ruby 2nd edition recently, and in the end of Chapter 5, they provide a little quiz that

> Your task is to change `Fixnum` class so that the answer to `1+1` becomes `3`, instead of `2`.

I understand the solution in the textbook without much trouble (They reopen `Fixnum` class directly). But I wanted to give a try  isolating methods to an independent `Module` as much as possible. something like below.

But running below result in infinite lop inside newly defined `+`. Could you point out what's wrong with this code? Thank you in advance.

```
module PlusOneMore
  def self.prepended(base)
    base.class_eval{
      alias_method :original_plus, :+
    }
  end
  def +(n)
    original_plus(n).original_plus(1)
  end
end

Fixnum.class_eval do
  prepend PlusOneMore
end

puts 1.+(1)
```

Comment: I can also confirm that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your override has *already occurred* when the `prepended` hook is executed. I.e. when you run `alias_method :original_plus, :+`, `+` already points to your override.

You need to either make sure the new method is defined *after* the `alias_method` call or use some other approach.

```
module Foo
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval do 
      alias_method :original_plus, :+
      define_method(:+) do |n|
        original_plus(n).original_plus(1)
      end
    end
  end
end

Fixnum.include(Foo)

puts 1.+(1)
# => 3
```

You could also use `prepend` with `super` and `succ`:

```
module Foo
  def +(n)
    super(n.succ)
  end
end

Fixnum.prepend(Foo)

puts 1.+(1)
# => 3
```

Comment: This. The *whole point* of `prepend`, the *very reason* why it was introduced in the first place, is to *get rid of* that godawful `alias_method` dance.

Comment: Can't see how it's invalid. OP refers to changing Fixnum, not float. This evals just fine on ruby 2.2.2: `ruby -e 'puts 1.+(1)'`

Comment: My apologies. I was running your code in IRB! Of course that won't work. :-) (I'd like to look at this more carefully in the morning. For now, Mr. Sandman has been calling.)

Comment: @Jesper Thank you! I now see the correct order of defining things (also I really like the conciseness of your `prepend` solution.

Comment: @Jesper Yet another question is, why can't we use `prepend` in your first solution? I tried it, and it just returns normal `1 + 1 = 2` computation.

Comment: Okazaki, in the first solution  `prepend` works fine. Did you by chance forget to change `self.included(klass)` to `self.prepended(klass)`?

Comment: @OkazakiMiyamaYuta I did some testing and it seems using prepend like I use include in my first solution only works in ruby 2.3, there seems to have been a bug in earlier versions. Tried this on 2.2.2 and it didn't work. 2.3.0 works.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Ruby refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) to achieve similar effect.

```
module Foo
  refine Fixnum do 
    alias_method :original_plus, :+
    def +(n)
      (self.original_plus(n)).next
    end
  end
end

using Foo

puts 1 + 1
#=> 3
```